# How do I avoid continual issues with multiple programs (git, ruby, python) and default network drive path problems?

Tags: ruby, windows, git, installation

Windows 7 PC.  Our network admin has a network drive (H: drive)that installs on restart.....which I do not have access to when not in the office (or is not available via VPN).  I have learned to both install apps after disconnecting the network drive and disconnect the network drive by default when at home.

Yet.. it seems that just about anything I install has problems that are not overt install issues.  Ruby, Git and Python all install, but have problems.

The latest incarnation is the installation of Git. It installed fine, but when I tried to create a new directory, it gave me the following error

```
error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig: No such file or directory
    while executing
"exec {C:/Program Files/Git/libexec/git-core/git-config.exe} --global --add gui.recentrepo C:/Users/myname/Desktop/Testing/projects"
    ("eval" body line 1)
    invoked from within
```

YET... it still added files to a git folder. It would not allow me to open what I just created.

I am looking for a fix to my .git problem, but I am really looking for clues to a magic bullet on this underlying network issue that continues to be a major roadblock in making headway in my learning experience.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: This really seems like it'd fit better on http://superuser.com as it's more about system administration and file permissions than it is about specific programming/code bugs or issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
error: could not lock config file H:\/.gitconfig:
```

That because of the environment variable `HOME`: make sure to define one which doesn't involve H:\, and git will work just fine.

If you want all programs installed in a custom directory, like C:\prgs, use my project **[senv](https://github.com/VonC/senv)**.
All programs installed are "portable": simple unzip in their respective folders, no registry modification, no uninstall (simply delete the folder when you don't want a program anymore).

Unzip https://github.com/VonC/senv/archive/master.zip anywhere you want, unzip it, and execute `senv.bat`: it will install git, python, ruby in a portable way.

---

The [OP user1525974](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1525974/user1525974) reports [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20307025/how-do-i-avoid-continual-issues-with-multiple-programs-git-ruby-python-and-d/20307393#comment30324015_20307393) adding to the `gem.bat` file:

```
SET _HOMEDRIVE=%HOMEDRIVE% 
SET _HOMEPATH=%HOMEPATH% 
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:
SET HOMEPATH=/Ruby193
```

Comment: I did up finding an answer that seems to work I addedSET _HOMEDRIVE=%HOMEDRIVE%
SET _HOMEPATH=%HOMEPATH%
SET HOMEDRIVE=C:   to the gem.bat file.
SET HOMEPATH=/Ruby193

Comment: @user1525974 ok, I have added your findings in the answer for more visibility